# How to programmatically get a hostname's IP address on a local network in C?

Tags: networking, c

I'm working on a project where I'd like to transfer data over TCP/IP sockets in a C program between two computers connected over WiFi to a home router, both are running Debian-based Linix distributions. I'd like to be able to connect from the client machine with only knowledge of a hostname of the device. I don't have control over the router and so I can't set a static IP for the device.

Is there an API available for retrieving an IP address given a hostname and where could I go for more information on using that API in C?

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/getaddrinfo.3

Comment: +1 for getaddrinfo() but actually this may just not be possible on a home network depending on DNS and DHCP configuration - if you're using ISP DNS servers directly then the router (which knows hostname to IP mapping) won't provide an answer.

Comment: it's not the best interface anyway (not asynchronous etc), but it's not either doing only dns resolution. it could do mDNS (avahi/zeroconf/bonjour ...) resolution if nsswitch.conf tells to